# convert date data into mysql date format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to convert the data on which I have the format

```
$dateToday = date("d-m-Y");
```

so the value of $dateToday is **27-12-2012**

Then I want to save it to the database with the mysql data type *date*. How to keep the value of **27-12-2012** it can be stored in the mysql database with the format **2012-12-27**?
Help me please. Thank you

Comment: Why you need to store your date in that format? You always can format the date properly when you need it

Comment: it can easily done using php's function strtotime, check my answer below,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can convert the date with `strtotime();`

```
$dateToday = date("d-m-Y");
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateToday));
```

OUTPUT: **2012-12-27**

And then you can store data to your database.

When you have to recover the date you can reverse this operation like this:

```
$dateFromDatabase = "2012-12-27";
$reverseDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dateFromDatabase));
```

OUTPUT: **27-12-2012**

(corrected "Y-m-d" to "d-m-Y" in 2nd date call)

Comment: yes, that's work. thank you very much friends. it's very help me :)

Comment: it will not work for if i input 04-03-2015 in US format

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data in MYSQL table in this format, you need to declare the column as `varchar`.

Because the `datetime`  store date in a different format like `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'`

Answer (score 0):

this is how it works:

You have to **store** your data in the proper mysql format. It will allow you to make whatever ordering, aggregating, filtering and calculating your dates.

But when you need to **display** your data, you may convert it in whatever format you wish, using mysql `DATE_FORMAT()` function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as dtf FROM TABLE
```

will give you `dtf` field formatted in your custom format

Answer (score 0):

i'll show u how to do that.
To explain i create one table called `testtable1` it contain only one column called 
`col1` of type DATE
Table creation query is given below

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable1` (
    `col1` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Following query will work as you need.
In the first line i declared a string variable. In the second line i converted that string to your required date format and inserted into table.

```
set @var1='27-12-2012';
insert into testtable1 values(STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use the mysql function for converting to a date from a string, i.e 
[STR_TO_TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
.
The SQL query could be

```
INSERT INTO foo_table (foo_date)
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('27-12-2012','%d,%m,%Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is wrong This cannot show the date from the database .This show 1970/01/01..... 
$date=Date($year."/". $month."/". $day);
 $date=Date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
echo $date;`enter code here`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$dateToday = date("d-m-Y");
$dateForMysql = date('Y-m-d', $dateToday));
```